# Elevated authorization for Automator Applications

Tags: macos, automator

I have created applications using the Automator app on Mac. when these applications are first opened they always request access to open the required apps such as Mail or Messages.
Is there a way where to automatically allow these custom applications to open with authorization for the first time automatically?

I want to create Calendar events with these applications set to open at the scheduled time, but they won't function unless I click allow for it to access other apps and such.

Comment: The current permissions model is to ask the first time the application is run - are you saying it asks each time?